# MadelineProto: channels.editBanned не работает (Telegram API)

Tags: php, telegram, madelineproto

Использую MadelineProto для взаимодействия с Telegram API. 
Нужно забанить/выкинуть пользователя из приватного канала – для этого есть метод [channels.editBanned](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/channels_editBanned.html).

Но по какой-то причине все время возращает пустой updates и users, соответственного никого из канала не удаляет.

Id указываю в формате channel#id и user#id в соответствии с документацией.

Banned rights: ['_' => 'chatBannedRights', 'until_date' => 0]

Код:

```
//Подключение Madeline с гитхаба
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', __DIR__ . '/madeline.php');
}
include __DIR__ . '/madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

$me = $MadelineProto->get_self();

\danog\MadelineProto\Logger::log($me);

try {

    //Get user id by phone
    $inputPhoneContact = ['_' => 'inputPhoneContact', 'client_id' => '0', 'phone' => '+XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'first_name' => 'Name', 'last_name' => ''];
    $importedContact = $MadelineProto->contacts->importContacts(['contacts' => [$inputPhoneContact], ]);

    //Channel
    $inputChannel = "channel#XXXXXXXX";
    //Input User
    $inputUser = 'user#'.$importedContact['imported'][0]['user_id'];

    //Add user to channel
    $Updates = $MadelineProto->channels->inviteToChannel(['channel' => $inputChannel, 'users' => [$inputUser],]);

    //Chat Banned Rights
    $chatBannedRights = ['_' => 'chatBannedRights', 'view_messages' => false, 'send_messages' => false, 'send_media' => false, 'send_stickers' => false, 'send_gifs' => false, 'send_games' => false, 'send_inline' => false, 'embed_links' => false, 'send_polls' => false, 'change_info' => false, 'invite_users' => false, 'pin_messages' => false, 'until_date' => '0'];

    //Kick user from channel
    $Updates = $MadelineProto->channels->editBanned(['channel' => $inputChannel, 'user_id' => $inputUser, 'banned_rights' => ['_' => 'chatBannedRights', 'until_date' => 0], ]);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

К слову, [channels.inviteToChanne](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/channels_inviteToChannel.html)l работает без проблем.

Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня похожая ситуация только на zerobias/telegram-mtproto. А вообще из документации все флаги инверсны. То есть если нужно забанить тогда указать True

Comment: С инверсными флагами все работает. Не обратил внимания на инверсные флаги.